# How to approach out-of-core machine learning

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, tensorflow, google-cloud-storage

I have large data set in Google Cloud Storage (csv; around 300 GB; CRM data on customers) and I intend to create a model which will predict comeback of our customers on our site.

I am evaluating several alternatives:

**Processing and data cleansing**

1. Read data by chunks in pandas; clean data and create features using pandas methods and other python libraries;
2. Read data line by line in numpy array; clean data and create features using python (without pandas methods)

**Machine learning**

1. Use some scikit-learn method (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/scaling_strategies.html) for incremental learning for fitting data.
2. Vowpal Wabbit
3. TensorFlow (logistic regression for example)

From the hardware side I have server with 8 GB RAM and potential access to small (standard) Google Cloud instance. Also I am going to automate this task and create some Data Pipeline for everyday prediction. Previously, I used Pandas+Scikit-learn for machine learning, but in this problem data doesn't fit in memory.

1. Which approach should I pursue for this task?
2. Are there some tree algorithms for incremental learning (Gradient Boosting, Random Forest)? They are more preferable, because they have good performance without much data preparation and scaling.

Comment: How did you solve this problem?